# How perform GridCache.forEach() concurrently and partitioned on all nodes?

Tags: caching, gridgain

[With code:](https://github.com/ceefour/lumen-kb/blob/8ff8be4b49364178e18354893f4620ca78653d23/cli/src/main/java/id/ac/itb/ee/lskk/lumen/yago/AnswerYagoFactTests.java)

```
try (Grid grid = GridGain.start(AnswerYagoFactTests.class.getResource("yago.gridgain.xml"))) {
    GridCache<Integer, YagoRule> cache = grid.cache("yagoRules");
    grid.compute().broadcast(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                log.info("Cache formerly has size={} offheap={} overflow={}",
                        cache.size(), cache.offHeapEntriesCount(), cache.overflowSize());
            } catch (GridException e) {
                log.error("Cannot get overflow size", e);
            }
        }
    }).get();

    log.info("1 is {}", cache.get(1));
    grid.compute().apply(new GridClosure<String, String>() {
        @Override
        public String apply(String e) {
            log.info("Found {} YAGO rules", cache.size());
            cache.forEach(new GridInClosure<GridCacheEntry<Integer,YagoRule>>() {
                @Override
                public void apply(GridCacheEntry<Integer, YagoRule> e) {
                    log.info("Processing rule #{} {}", e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                }
            });
            return null;
        }
    }, msg).get();
}
```

In 3 node configuration. GridGain selects one node (seem to be random), then processes each "Processing rule" in that node only.

What I'd like to do is make the `forEach` parallel, so ideally for 3 nodes and 30 entries, each node should process 10 entries. The cache is `partitioned` so each node has its own entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, instead of `grid.compute().apply(...)` try using `grid.compute().broadcast(...)` and the closure will be broadcast to all nodes in the grid.

Also if you need to iterate only through primary set (excluding backups), you can do it as following:

```
grid.compute().broadcast(new GridClosure<String, Integer>() {
    @Override public String apply(String e) {
        for (GridCacheEntry<Integer, YagoRule> e : cache.primaryEntrySet()
            log.info("Processing rule #{} {}", e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}, msg).get();
```

Comment: This would not work as expected because there will be duplicates. i.e. node1 contains A, B, C and node2 contains B, C, D. I'd like exactly these 4 entries to be processed (no matter who does it).

Comment: @HendyIrawan Sounds like you need to use "primaryEntrySet()" method. I updated the example in my answer.